# Problems lowercasing each word in a pandas dataframe column with lists of strings

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe

As the title says, I'm trying to lowercase each element in a list of strings on a dataframe column.

Example of what I have:

```
df
   A
0  [Verapamil hydrochloride]  
1  [Simvastatin]  
2  [Sulfamethoxazole, Trimethoprim]
```

Example of what I want to have:

```
df
   A
0  [verapamil hydrochloride]  
1  [simvastatin]  
2  [sulfamethoxazole, trimethoprim]
```

I tried using:

```
df['A'].apply(lambda x: [w.lower() for w in x])
```

but it outputs:
`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

When checking individually it does not identify any floats

```
type(df['A'][0])
#Out: list

type(df['A'][0][0])
#Out: str
```

I'm doing this because I want to compare lists later using `set()`, because not only the elements in the other lists can have the `strings` in lowercase, but can also change the order within the lists.

I don't really know what to do, because I can't find the reasons for that error. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Share an example with the data so that I can play around it.

Comment: your code works fine for me. Do you have x or w defined somewhere else in the program? I think you can check your editor and re run all the variables.

Comment: I think some data in this column may contain values other than list that will create TypeError.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi is there a way to find the alleged `float`?

Comment: @user2736738 maybe the best would be to send the full dataset, with all values for that specific column. Where can I send you?

Comment: @PedroDomingues You can simply share a portion of the dataset either by posting it here in SO question itself or git gist.

Comment: @user2736738 Thank you. Here it is: [CSV file](https://gist.github.com/pedromingues/b9051275e77d96e616de7b8f6b43b0d3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('DCI.csv')
df['ActiveSubstances'] = df['ActiveSubstances'].astype(str)
df['ActiveSubstances'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['ActiveSubstances'].lower(), axis=1)
print(df)
```

##### Output

```
                            ActiveSubstances
0                ['verapamil hydrochloride']
1                ['verapamil hydrochloride']
2                ['verapamil hydrochloride']
3                            ['simvastatin']
4                            ['simvastatin']
...                                      ...
192520             ['doxepin hydrochloride']
192521             ['doxepin hydrochloride']
192522                      ['ethosuximide']
192523           ['fludrocortisone acetate']
192524  ['sulfamethoxazole', 'trimethoprim']

[192525 rows x 1 columns]
```

Converting to `str` and then applying `lower()` solves it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
variable.lowercase()
```